# Site-to-site IPSEC for multiple peers with dynamic IP on Juniper SRX

Tags: juniper, ipsec, srx, site-to-site

Looking for possible solution.

I have Juniper SRX 1400 (12.1X47-D20.7) with static WAN IP in data-center and multiple sites with dynamic WAN IP addresses. I need to build with them site-to-site VPN's. All what I've found is a multiple **ike gateways** configured with **ike policy** using **aggressive mode**. Most of examples shows single IPSEC connection between static ip gateway and dynamic ip endpoint.

[This](http://www.firewall.cx/cisco-technical-knowledgebase/cisco-routers/936-cisco-router-vpn-dynamic-endpoint.html) article shows configuration example for Cisco routers, and I'm wondering if I could do something similar on SRX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a 'thumbnail' sketch of how to do it provided you have SRX's on both ends:

https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB28077&cat=SRX_SERIES&actp=LIST

The basic idea is that you use a 'hostname' in the IKE gateway setup on both sides. The SRX with the dynamic IP will establish IKE using the hostname.

Comment: Yes, saw that. Probably the best way to do this.